# Combinar filas devueltas con las mismas columnas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una consulta sql de ésta forma:

```
  select e.activa, e.id_entidad ,e.Alias 'Empresa' ,dir.calle 'Dirección' ,dir.desc_adicional 'Dirección adicional' ,dir.codigo_postal 'Código postal' ,loc.localidad 'Población' ,p.provincia 'Provincia' ,e.telefono 'Teléfono' ,e.cif 'CIF' ,e.web 'Web' ,
  CASE WHEN d.contacto_entidad = 1 THEN d.nombre  ELSE ' ' END AS 'Nombre - Contacto Sector',
  CASE WHEN d.contacto_entidad = 1 THEN d.email  ELSE ' ' END AS 'E-mail - Contacto Sector',
  case when d.rep_legal_entidad = 1 then d.nombre else ' ' end as 'Nombre - Responsable Legal',
  case when d.rep_legal_entidad = 1 then d.email else ' ' end as 'E-mail - Responsable legal' 
  from entidades e left outer join direcciones as dir on e.dom_comercial = dir.id_direccion 
  and( dir.activa = 'S' and e.id_tipoentidad = 1) 
  left outer join Directivos as d on d.id_entidad = e.id_entidad
  and (d.contacto_entidad = 1 or d.rep_legal_entidad = 1) 
  and d.activa = 'S' 
  left outer join localidades as loc on loc.id_localidad = dir.id_localidades
  and loc.activa = 'S'
  left outer join Provincias as p on p.id_provincia = loc.id_provincia
  and p.activa = 'S'  where e.activa = 'S' order by e.nombre
```

El problema que tengo es que me devuelve registros en los que todos los campos son iguales pero se podrían combinar los campos en blancos con los rellenos, como se ven la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ëstos campos en blanco nunca estarán rellenos en los dos registros

En la imagen los campos tachados son iguales arriba y abajo, salvo los que están en uno y no en  otro lógicamente.
¿Cómo puedo juntar los registros "repetidos"?

Comment: Disculpa, Tomás, no lo he entendido muy bien. Quieres una sola fila en tu ejemplo, ¿pero siempre y cuando haya coincidencias de todos los campos de los registros, cuando en uno esté vacío y en otro no,...?

Comment: Así es, son registros iguales excepto por una serie de campos que si uno no lo tiene el otro puede. por ejemplo la entidad 1 tiene dos registros en la select, éstos son igulaes salvo en unos campos que nunca estarán rellenos en los dos registros, por lo que siempre se podrán combinar

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude conseguir con un group by de todos los campos y haciendo un max de los que podían estra en blanco (el cast es porque no se puede hacer max con datos de tipo byte)

```
  (select e.activa, e.id_entidad ,e.Alias 'Empresa' ,dir.calle 'Dirección' ,dir.desc_adicional 'Dirección adicional' ,dir.codigo_postal 'Código postal' ,loc.localidad 'Población' ,p.provincia 'Provincia' ,e.telefono 'Teléfono' ,e.cif 'CIF' ,e.web 'Web' ,
  CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(d.contacto_entidad as int)) = 1 THEN max(d.nombre)  ELSE ' ' END AS 'Nombre - Contacto Sector',
  CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(d.contacto_entidad AS INT )) = 1 THEN max(d.email)  ELSE ' ' END AS 'E-mail - Contacto Sector',
  case when MAX(CAST(d.rep_legal_entidad AS INT)) = 1 then max(d.nombre) else ' ' end as 'Nombre - Responsable Legal',
  case when MAX(CAST(d.rep_legal_entidad AS INT)) = 1 then max(d.email) else ' ' end as 'E-mail - Responsable legal' 
  from entidades e
  left outer join direcciones as dir on e.dom_comercial = dir.id_direccion 
  and( dir.activa = 'S' and e.id_tipoentidad = 1 ) 
  left outer join Directivos as d on d.id_entidad = e.id_entidad
  and (d.contacto_entidad = 1 or d.rep_legal_entidad = 1) 
  and d.activa = 'S'
  left outer join localidades as loc on loc.id_localidad = dir.id_localidades
  and loc.activa = 'S' 
  left outer join Provincias as p on p.id_provincia = loc.id_provincia 
  and p.activa = 'S'  where e.activa = 'S'
  group by e.Alias, e.activa,e.id_entidad,dir.calle,dir.desc_adicional,dir.codigo_postal,loc.localidad,p.provincia,e.telefono,e.cif,e.web)
```

Un saludo y gracias.